# Unable to remove nor reinstall docker-ce; Both apt and dpkg hang without error in CLI

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall, reinstall

I initially tried to reinstall the docker-ce package when its service was not starting successfully but reinstall would hang at 20% progress. When that wouldn't work I attempted to remove it, and then purging it as well.

I've also tried a handful of methods to try and remedy this including [`apt -f -install`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWLTP.jpg), and [`sudo dpkg -r --force-depends docker-ce:amd64`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bSCe.png) commands without success

And running `ps -Af` during the latter command's hanging yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FatHx.png).

Just tried reinstall and removal through Synaptic Package Manager know it likely wouldn't be any different, and yeah, no dice.

Is there a way to reinstall or remove a package that I haven't tried? How would I go about finding out what is at the root of this problem? As far as I can tell, it's the only package doing this; everything else functions like normal.

Thanks,
Ken

dpkg:
[dpkg.log](https://gist.github.com/KTheMan/e9c28303dd6565f9c30dd6bcd8c9f855)

apt: [history.log](https://gist.github.com/KTheMan/77bebe7da3b5c6f150a3b4ea55dd2e91), [term.log](https://gist.github.com/KTheMan/e10eb34053b4682626b59f4b063b715d)